# How to show console while running a script?

Tags: raspberry-pi

So I'm running a script and I want to be able to type in the console at the same time.
Usually I would press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but that stops the script from running which I don't want.

- So how do I bring up the console without stopping a running script?

Answer (score 4):

Put the running script in the background, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> then `bg`. If you know from the beginning that you want to run a command in the background, add `&` to the command line: this will immediately place the command in the background.

You might find `screen` or `tmux` interesting: they provide multiple “consoles” you can run commands in. If you’re directly connected to your system’s console, you should also have multiple virtual consoles, accessible using <kbd>Alt</kbd> combined with the function keys <kbd>F1</kbd> etc.

Answer (score 3):

(assuming bash)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> pauses the script instead.
Then you can use job control.  The primary commands are:

`jobs`, lists the jobs
`bg`, moves the last job to background
`fg`, brings the first job to the foreground

Also, you can spawn a process in the background by using a `&` at the end of the command.  The job control commands are usable in this case too.  See `man jobs` for more info.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the sign `&` at the end of your command, like this : `sh my_script.sh &`

This will make your script run in the background and you'll be able to use your console while it's running.

You can also use programs like `tmux` or `screen` to create virtual terminal that can run even when they don't run in an active tty.

You can find more informations on the [tmux archwiki post](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjfsYfFjvPXAhVCnRoKHbMNAdcQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwiki.archlinux.org%2Findex.php%2Ftmux&usg=AOvVaw3SdLUGU-sRwKeiRBQduBlU) and the [screen archwiki post](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Screen)